# How to increase webview height dynamically in android

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to increase the webview height dynamically in android? My webview content will come some time less and sometimes I have to show webview full layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this code

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

then you find web view height automatically increase.